# What is the Japanese word for the Australian bush/outback?

Tags: translation

[image: The aussie bush]
I don't know if it would just be the Australian forest, or something else. I would like this for a speaking task at school, and I cannot find any good translations.

Comment: Do you need something specific to Australia or just a term for any kind of light forest? Please check discussion under mackygoo's answer

Answer (score 3):

I think it'd normally be translated as...

> 「アウトバック」 ([Wiki](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%88%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF))
>
> 「アウトバック」, 「オーストラリアの[奥地]{おくち}, [内陸部]{ないりくぶ}, or [内地]{ないち}」 ([コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%88%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-422080#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88), [研究社新英和中辞典](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/outback))

Answer (score 1):

When searching on the Internet with the keyword "**雑木林{ぞうきばやし}**", I found a lot of photos to introduce below.
Is "雑木林｛ぞうきばやし｝" the word you want?
[image]

---

## EDIT

I think that the reason why my original answer got a down-vote is because the answer was insufficient, so I'll add some information.

(1) The photo presented by the questioner may be very misleading.
If you actually search for "Australian outback" on the internet, you can find photographs of wasteland with less rain (let's call them as Photo A) as introduced below.
Photo A is quite different from the photo presented by the questioner (let's call it Photo B). Also, there is no scenery like Photo A in Japan. However, the scenery like Photo B seems to be in Japan.
I think that it looks like the scenery I searched for by the key word with "雑木林｛ぞうきばやし｝" I introduced in my original answer.

(2) **There is no Japanese word** equivalent to "Australian outback" in the usual sense. Naturally it is not called "雑木林" either.
As you probably know, words are not created unless objects corresponding to them exist.
In Japan where there is no scenery like Photo A, the word expressing it is unnecessary unless it is necessary for translation or academic use. "アウトバック" in Chocolate's answer seems to be Japanese at first glance, but this is not a common Japanese but an academic term or the like.　Ordinary Japanese people including me have never used the word "アウトバック" or they cannot imagine Photo A from this word.

(3) When considering what kind of words Photo A corresponds to in Japanese, I can think of "乾燥地帯{かんそうちたい} *Dry Zone*", "荒｛あ｝れ野｛の｝ / 荒｛あ｝れ地｛ち｝ *Wilderness*" and "荒野｛こうや｝ *Wasted Land*", etc.
In the explanatory sentence in Chocolate's answer, words "内地｛ないち｝" and "奥地｛おくち｝" are used.
In general, it is difficult to imagine Photo A from the word "内地｛ないち｝" in Japanese. There are implications of "ジャングル *jungle*  / 密林｛みつりん｝ *jungle*" and "a place where people are hard to approach" in "奥地｛おくち｝" in Japanese.
In any case, the image of wasteland that you can see far away in Photo A is not in Japanese "奥地". Therefore, "Australian outback" is quite a lot different from the Japanese word "内地" or "奥地".

(4) As the word associated with Photo A presented by the questioner, I introduced the word "雑木林" in my first answer. When searching for the meaning of "a place or a forest where people seldom approach" in Japanese words, "密林｛みつりん｝ *Jungle*", "自然林｛しぜんりん｝ *Natural forest*", "森林｛しんりん｝ *Forest*", "樹海｛じゅかい｝ *Broad expanse of dense woodland*" and the like come out.
However, using these words as keywords and examining them on the Internet, they have images completely different from "Australian outback".

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: The OP (well, at least the question title) asks for the Japanese word for the term "the Australian bush/outback", which has a specific reference and, I suspect, unique associations.(According to Wikipedia: "The Outback is the vast, remote interior of Australia. "The Outback" is more remote than those areas named "the bush" which is any location outside the main urban areas.")

Comment: This answer suggests "雑木林", apparently on the grounds that the Google search on this term returns images that look similar to that in the question ("白神山地", by the way, returns similar looking images -- a bunch of trees, basically -- too, but of course 白神山地 is not the Australian outback), without actually explaining the meaning or associations of the word (which I doubt quite match up with those of "the Australian bush/outback") and then invites the OP to reach their own judgement... which I am pessimistic this post helps to be well-informed.

Comment: However, I'm not sure what they meant by "I don't know if it would just be the Australian forest, or something else." Were they saying the sought-after term doesn't have to refer specifically to "the Australian bush/outback", but to any *type* of thing that the referent of the term "the Australian bush/outback" can be described as? If that's the case "雑木林" might not be so far off the mark after all...